# Authentication using SAML in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

Actually we are developing a application, 
in Spring boot 1.5 and authentication and authorization done with spring security with oauth2 implementation , now we have a requirement,
in authentication part, splitting the authentication and move the authentication part to third party which is SAML integration,

> **Flow:**             login->SAML authentication-> authenticated user
>   ->authorization part which we handle(role part)->generate our token ->user access resources with this token only.

how to authorize the user in my spring security with userid only and generate custom token(customizing any spring security filter),

how to populate Authentication object in my Spring security Filters(if AuthenticationProvider is used),

best way to redirect to IDP in SAML authentication server .

best way to implement logout functionality.

how can I implement these requirement,can anyone suggest as I am new to this.

My current configuration
Every thing is Java configured,

```
**spring security,Resource server,Authorization server**
```

I am worked on a sample provided in documention,
https://github.com/vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample

when started the spring boot Application following error occured,

> 2017-12-29 10:15:12.192 ERROR 25076 --- [Metadata-reload]
>   o.o.s.m.p.HTTPMetadataProvider           : Error retrieving metadata
>   from http://idp.ssocircle.com/idp-meta.xml
>
> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect    at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_66]     at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_66]     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_66]     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_66]     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_66]     at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_66]     at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_66]     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_66]     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_66]     at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:434)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_66]     at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:286)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_66]     at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:80)
>   ~[commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:?]   at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:122)
>   ~[commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:?]   at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
>   ~[commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:?]   at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1361)
>   ~[commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:?]   at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
>   ~[commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:?]   at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
>   ~[commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:?]   at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
>   ~[commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:?]   at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
>   ~[commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:?]   at
>   org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider.fetchMetadata(HTTPMetadataProvider.java:250)
>   [opensaml-2.6.1.jar:?]    at
>   org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.refresh(AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.java:255)
>   [opensaml-2.6.1.jar:?]    at
>   org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.doInitialization(AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.java:236)
>   [opensaml-2.6.1.jar:?]    at
>   org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractMetadataProvider.initialize(AbstractMetadataProvider.java:407)
>   [opensaml-2.6.1.jar:?]    at
>   org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate.initialize(ExtendedMetadataDelegate.java:167)
>   [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataManager.initializeProvider(MetadataManager.java:412)
>   [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataManager.refreshMetadata(MetadataManager.java:238)
>   [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager.refreshMetadata(CachingMetadataManager.java:86)
>   [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataManager$RefreshTask.run(MetadataManager.java:1040)
>   [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]  at
>   java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555) [?:1.8.0_66]   at
>   java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505) [?:1.8.0_66]
>
> 2017-12-29 10:15:12.193 DEBUG 25076 --- [Metadata-reload]
>   .s.m.p.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider : Error occurred while
>   attempting to refresh metadata from
>   'http://idp.ssocircle.com/idp-meta.xml'
>
> org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException: Error
>   retrieving metadata from http://idp.ssocircle.com/idp-meta.xml    at
>   org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider.fetchMetadata(HTTPMetadataProvider.java:274)
>   ~[opensaml-2.6.1.jar:?]   at
>   org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.refresh(AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.java:255)
>   [opensaml-2.6.1.jar:?]    at
>   org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.doInitialization(AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.java:236)
>   [opensaml-2.6.1.jar:?]    at
>   org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractMetadataProvider.initialize(AbstractMetadataProvider.java:407)
>   [opensaml-2.6.1.jar:?]    at
>   org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate.initialize(ExtendedMetadataDelegate.java:167)
>   [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataManager.initializeProvider(MetadataManager.java:412)
>   [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataManager.refreshMetadata(MetadataManager.java:238)
>   [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager.refreshMetadata(CachingMetadataManager.java:86)
>   [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataManager$RefreshTask.run(MetadataManager.java:1040)
>   [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]  at
>   java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555) [?:1.8.0_66]   at
>   java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505) [?:1.8.0_66] Caused by:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect    at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_66]     at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_66]     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_66]     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_66]     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_66]     at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_66]     at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_66]     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_66]     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_66]     at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:434)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_66]     at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:286)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_66]     at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:80)
>   ~[commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:?]   at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:122)
>   ~[commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:?]   at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
>   ~[commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:?]   at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1361)
>   ~[commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:?]   at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
>   ~[commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:?]   at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
>   ~[commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:?]   at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
>   ~[commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:?]   at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
>   ~[commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:?]   at
>   org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider.fetchMetadata(HTTPMetadataProvider.java:250)
>   ~[opensaml-2.6.1.jar:?]   ... 10 more
>
> 2017-12-29 10:15:12.194  INFO 25076 --- [Metadata-reload]
>   .s.m.p.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider : Next refresh cycle for
>   metadata provider 'http://idp.ssocircle.com/idp-meta.xml' will occur
>   on '2017-12-29T04:50:12.194Z' ('2017-12-29T10:20:12.194+05:30' local
>   time) 2017-12-29 10:15:12.194 ERROR 25076 --- [Metadata-reload]
>   o.o.s.m.p.AbstractMetadataProvider       : Metadata provider failed to
>   properly initialize, fail-fast=true, halting
>
> org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException:
>   org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException: Error
>   retrieving metadata from http://idp.ssocircle.com/idp-meta.xml    at
>   org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.refresh(AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.java:267)
>   ~[opensaml-2.6.1.jar:?]   at
>   org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.doInitialization(AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.java:236)
>   ~[opensaml-2.6.1.jar:?]   at
>   org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractMetadataProvider.initialize(AbstractMetadataProvider.java:407)
>   [opensaml-2.6.1.jar:?]    at
>   org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate.initialize(ExtendedMetadataDelegate.java:167)
>   [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataManager.initializeProvider(MetadataManager.java:412)
>   [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataManager.refreshMetadata(MetadataManager.java:238)
>   [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager.refreshMetadata(CachingMetadataManager.java:86)
>   [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataManager$RefreshTask.run(MetadataManager.java:1040)
>   [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]  at
>   java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555) [?:1.8.0_66]   at
>   java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505) [?:1.8.0_66] Caused by:
>   org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException: Error
>   retrieving metadata from http://idp.ssocircle.com/idp-meta.xml    at
>   org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider.fetchMetadata(HTTPMetadataProvider.java:274)
>   ~[opensaml-2.6.1.jar:?]   at
>   org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.refresh(AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.java:255)
>   ~[opensaml-2.6.1.jar:?]   ... 9 more Caused by:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect    at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_66]     at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_66]     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_66]     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_66]     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_66]     at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_66]     at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_66]     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_66]     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_66]     at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:434)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_66]     at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:286)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_66]     at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:80)
>   ~[commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:?]   at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:122)
>   ~[commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:?]   at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
>   ~[commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:?]   at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1361)
>   ~[commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:?]   at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
>   ~[commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:?]   at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
>   ~[commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:?]   at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
>   ~[commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:?]   at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
>   ~[commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:?]   at
>   org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider.fetchMetadata(HTTPMetadataProvider.java:250)
>   ~[opensaml-2.6.1.jar:?]   at
>   org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.refresh(AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.java:255)
>   ~[opensaml-2.6.1.jar:?]   ... 9 more
>
> 2017-12-29 10:15:12.195 ERROR 25076 --- [Metadata-reload]
>   o.s.s.s.m.MetadataManager                : Initialization of metadata
>   provider
>   org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider@6ae8b7
>   failed, provider will be ignored
>
> org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException:
>   org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException: Error
>   retrieving metadata from http://idp.ssocircle.com/idp-meta.xml    at
>   org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.refresh(AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.java:267)
>   ~[opensaml-2.6.1.jar:?]   at
>   org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.doInitialization(AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.java:236)
>   ~[opensaml-2.6.1.jar:?]   at
>   org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractMetadataProvider.initialize(AbstractMetadataProvider.java:407)
>   ~[opensaml-2.6.1.jar:?]   at
>   org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate.initialize(ExtendedMetadataDelegate.java:167)
>   ~[spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataManager.initializeProvider(MetadataManager.java:412)
>   ~[spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataManager.refreshMetadata(MetadataManager.java:238)
>   [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager.refreshMetadata(CachingMetadataManager.java:86)
>   [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataManager$RefreshTask.run(MetadataManager.java:1040)
>   [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]  at
>   java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555) [?:1.8.0_66]   at
>   java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505) [?:1.8.0_66] Caused by:
>   org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException: Error
>   retrieving metadata from http://idp.ssocircle.com/idp-meta.xml    at
>   org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider.fetchMetadata(HTTPMetadataProvider.java:274)
>   ~[opensaml-2.6.1.jar:?]   at
>   org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.refresh(AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.java:255)
>   ~[opensaml-2.6.1.jar:?]   ... 9 more Caused by:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect    at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_66]     at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_66]     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_66]     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_66]     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_66]     at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_66]     at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_66]     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_66]     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_66]     at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:434)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_66]     at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:286)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_66]     at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:80)
>   ~[commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:?]   at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:122)
>   ~[commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:?]   at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
>   ~[commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:?]   at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1361)
>   ~[commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:?]   at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
>   ~[commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:?]   at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
>   ~[commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:?]   at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
>   ~[commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:?]   at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
>   ~[commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:?]   at
>   org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider.fetchMetadata(HTTPMetadataProvider.java:250)
>   ~[opensaml-2.6.1.jar:?]   at
>   org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.refresh(AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.java:255)
>   ~[opensaml-2.6.1.jar:?]   ... 9 more
>
> 2017-12-29 10:15:12.196 DEBUG 25076 --- [Metadata-reload]
>   o.s.s.s.m.MetadataManager                : Reloading metadata was
>   finished

how to sort this error?
whether this sample can be run and tested in local environment? or i need some external configuration?

Comment: Could you please elaborate the question? What do you mean by “how to authorize the user in my spring security with userid only ” ?

Comment: authentication part is done in idp and on success it returns a assertion part as userid and groupid from as idp response, after that we have to go through our(SP side) spring security filters(custom authorization and role mapping), which takes only userid , no password  as parameter ,and generated custom tokens which are used for all api calls.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to start with implementing spring-saml extention in your SP first. It will help you with following requirements:

> how to populate Authentication object in my Spring security Filters(if
>   AuthenticationProvider is used),
>
> best way to redirect to IDP in SAML authentication server .
>
> best way to implement logout functionality.

After your app is able to authenticate the user with IDP through SAML, then extend the implementation of class **SAMLAuthenticationProvider** . 
This class receives the assertion from IDP and validates it. Once the assertion is validated, you can map the incoming authorities in SAML token, to your local authorities by having custom implementation of userContextMapper. In this part you can generate a JWT token and use it for all api calls. Most of the IDP's provide an interface to exchange the SAML token to OAuth2 access token. In that case, you do not have to generate any token.

Let me know if you need any further information or detail.

**Update:**

[image]

Comment: thanks for the response,
can u provide some sample configuration , as my "WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter"


can tell me how .antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll(), url will be treated

Comment: we have only single client to access the resource and only one idp, iam following this reference,
https://github.com/vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample

but its only for spring security but no oauth2 implemention, very hard find  spring security+oauth2 +saml configuration

Comment: what is the grant type in "AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter" in Oauth2?

"Most of the IDP's provide an interface to exchange the SAML token to OAuth2 access token" -- how this can be configured?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have any sample configuration for this specific use-case. But there are some points I want to clear:

1. Do not try to implement SAML and OAuth together in one go. This might create a complicated setup, and you will be more confused. As I suggested fresh start with Spring-Saml only, and try to authenticate the user with IDP with SAML. Forget about OAuth till you achieve this. Remember that spring-saml itself complex enough, and you need to have a good understanding of all configurations related to spring-saml before you jump to the next part.

Comment: Continuing to above comment...

2. Now you have a working application with Spring-SAML, user can take login and can access the protected resources. This is the point to configure your application to act as OAuth client. In my use-case, I used SAML 2.0 Bearer Assertion profile to get the access token, and used that token to access OAuth protected resource. For performance, I got this token at the time of authentication and stored it as user details(Refer my answer about extending SAMLAuthenticationProvider).

Comment: Whenever I received any request from browser to my client for services  e.g. <host>:<port>/service/rest/** I used to get token from security context and pass it to resource server. Please note that, the expiration time of access token may be less than the expiration time of SAML token received at the time of authentication. In that case, you either need to ask user to logout or silently get  new token with the help of some custom filter.

Comment: Found some useful articals on google.
1. http://blog.scottlogic.com/2015/11/19/oauth2-with-saml2.html
2. https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw74/helpdata/en/12/41087770d9441682e3e02958997846/frameset.htm
3.https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Exchanging+SAML2+Bearer+Tokens+with+OAuth2+-+SAML+Extension+Grant+Type

Comment: i have got the assertion in SAMLAuthenticationProvider , how to generate the oauth token?
can u plz provide some more details of this custom implementation of userContextMapper.

http://meuslivros.github.io/OAuth-2-0-Identity-and-Access-Management-Patterns/OEBPS/ch09s03.html

follwed this but doesnt work

Comment: To get Oauth2 token I followed this link and it worked very well. https://docs.wso2.com/m/mobile.action#page/60493984. Implementaion of userContextMapper totally depends on your application and requirements. In my case, I got the user role as part of  claims in SAML token and mapped it to the internal role of application. I will try to upload a sample code as soon as possible.

Comment: thanks...Right now , i am not able relate this link, with my use case, could you please provide ..some examples to generate oauth token after saml assertion ..i am not using any other tools or middle ware to generate token. Please provide samples in spring oauth 2 token generation.